# Fitch line overwrites Justifilation

Tags: lplfitch

I am trying to make a Logic proof derivation with the package  lplfitch, but the lines are too long for the package like, so how I make it adapt to that. (I already tried  with newline (\) but it just makes the justification overwrite the one before)

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{lplfitch}
  \begin{document}
  \fitchprf{}{
  \subproof{
    \pline[1.]{\forall m }[Gegeben]\\
    \pline[2.]{\forall x }[Gegeben]
  }{
    \pline[3.]{\forall m_1 m_2 \in M (\forall v_1 \in V(m_1) \forall v_2 \in V(m_2) \to
                \neg C(v_1, v_2) )}[1, 2, Modus Ponentz]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\brokenform` command (explained on page 4 of the `lplfitch` [documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lplfitch/lplfitch.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lplfitch}

\begin{document}

\fitchprf{}{
\subproof{
    \pline[1.]{\forall m }[Gegeben]\\
    \pline[2.]{\forall x }[Gegeben]
  }{
    \pline[3.]{\brokenform{\forall m_1 m_2 \in M (\forall v_1 \in V(m_1)}{\formula{\forall v_2 \in V(m_2) \to\neg C(v_1, v_2) )}}}[1, 2, Modus Ponentz]
  }
}

\end{document}
```

You can, of course, choose a different location to break the formula.

Note that the second argument of `\brokenform` must be wrapped in `\formula` since it may contain line breaks.